# How does the conditional form separate the four words it translates to?

Tags: condicional

From my understanding, the conditional form is a way of adding would, could, should and probably before a verb that it is conjugating. Although these 4 phrases are related, aren't they 4 different phrases? How do you know which of the 4 phrases is being used?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "aren't they 4 different phrases"? Of course they are, both in English and Spanish. Or "How do you know which of the 4 phrases is being used?" Because they are different conjugations. If what you want to know is how to translate them to (or use them in) Spanish, you should ask that. If you're asking something different, please clarify your question.

Comment: At first, I didn't either understand what he meant with *these 4 phrases*, so I thought it was related to the use of modals.

Comment: I learned in "
Frequently, the conditional is used to express probability, possibility, wonder or conjecture, and is usually translated as would, could, must have or probably." Here is where: http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/conditional.htm

Comment: Well, that page already provides a detailed explanation for your question. If what you mean is "How do I know if a conditional tense in Spanish is expressing probability, possibility, wonder or conjecture, since them all look the same in some cases?", then context is key. "Serían las seis" can mean "It must have been 6 o' clock", "It would be 6 o'clock" or "It probably was 6 o'clock". The only way to tell is because of the context. Generally, only one option will make sense. Btw, if you want someone to be notified you answered them, you have to write @ followed by their username (e.g., @Yay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spanish conditional translates to "would" + verb:

- Yo compraría esto (I would buy this). Focusing in the action itself.

"Could" and "Should", while similar, are conditionals for the verbs *poder* and *deber*, and turn them into auxiliary verbs for a periphrasis:

- Yo podría comprar esto (I could buy this). Focusing in the ability to do the action.
- Yo debería comprar esto (I should buy this). Focusing in the need to do the action.

"Probably" (*probablemente*) shouldn't give you a lot of trouble, since it's an adverb, independent of the previous cases.

Comment: So basically most verbs in conditional are would + verb. Conditional poder (can) is could and conditional deber (must) is should? Am I getting this correct?

Comment: @munchschair Yes. Each *would + base form* indicates the conditional for a verb; *could = podría,* *should = debería*. However, be careful with the use of *would + base form,* because it doesn´t always construct the conditional for a verb, it can also be used for a repeated action in the past: *my dad would always tell me stories = mi papá siempre me contaba historias.* (NOT *mi papá siempre me contaría historias.*)

Answer (score 2):

It depends of the conditional form.
In English, the three main conditionals use the modals you specify.

1. **First conditional**

   - *If you come with me, I **could** help you = Si vienes conmigo, **podría** ayudarte.*
     (Note that *could* can be replaced either by *will, might* or *may* to increase or decrease the possibility for something to happen.)
2. **Second conditional**

   - *If you came with me, I **would/could** help you = Si vinieras/vinieses conmigo, te **ayudaría** / te **podría ayudar**.*
   - *If you **could** come with me, I **would** help you = Si **pudieras/pudieses** venir conmigo, te **ayudaría**.*

*should* is different in this case, it can refer to the past tense of *must*, it can be used to give advice or it can be used with *have* to show that an action didn't take place when it should:

> » *You **should**'ve come to help me! = ¡**Debiste** haber venido a ayudarme!*

However, sentences like

> *This was what **should** happen = Esto fue lo que **debería/debiese/debiera/debió** pasar,*

should be avoided as not being grammatically correct. (See Yay's comment below.)

Comment: Neither "This was what should happen" nor "Esto fue lo que debería/debiese/debiera pasar" make much sense. The correct conjugation is "This was what should *have happened*" and "Esto fue lo que debería *haber pasado*". The forms *debiese/debiera* instead of *debería*, although common in some Latin American countries, aren't grammatically correct and should be avoided. Finally, "Esto fue lo que debió pasar" or "Esto fue lo que debió de pasar" would translate to "This is what *must have happened*"

Comment: I agree with your first part (and edited my answer), but the translation for *This is what must have happened* doesn't translate as you say since *must have* indicates certainty in the past. (Besides you used *is = fue.*)

Comment: Silly typo! I meant "This *was* what must have happened".

Comment: "must have" is an English phrase that does not mean what the two words mean separately.  It's a conjecture about something that happened based on something other than direct observation.

Comment: @Walter And so it is in Spanish.